# Is placeholder property available in <= IE8

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I understand the actual html5 placeholder functionality is not available < IE10, but will the actual tag property still be available?

To create my own custom placeholders, I use the following script:

```
if(core.isInput(el)) {
    el.initValue = str;
    el.txtColor = core.dom.css(el, 'color');
    var set = function() {
        if(el.value == '') {
            el.value = el.initValue;
            el.style.color = '#BDBAB5';
        }
    };
    set(); //Set the placeholder

    core.dom.on(el, 'focus', function() {
        if(this.value == this.initValue) {
            this.value = '';
            this.style.color = this.txtColor;
        }
    });

    core.dom.on(el, 'blur', set);
} else {
    console.error('Element is not an input.');
}
```

Rather than having to manually set the placeholder on the element, is it possible to do something like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    if(input.getAttribute('placeholder') != undefined) {
        //Set placeholder code
    }
}
```

In other words, if I set a placeholder in the HTML and the browser doesn't support them will the property still be available on the input when I use the getAttribute? When I do the input.getAttribute('placeholder') check, will the property I set initially be available or will the browser automatically remove the placeholder property if its not supported?

Currently I manually add the placeholder functionality for each input, but i'd rather use an automatic onload script to do the work. If I can't determine that the input is supposed to have a placeholder by detecting the placeholder value, it won't work.

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder

Comment: I'd prefer to write my own solution.

Comment: [Here's the support table](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder)

Comment: The point of writing my own? I'm just not a huge library user. If I can add the functionality myself with a few lines of code id rather not have to implement an entire library and a plugin for a simple solution. The question isn't about supporting placeholder, its about whether or not the placeholder property disappears when the browser doesn't support it.

Comment: Ya. So that does mean that the placeholder attribute will still be able, correct?

Comment: Cool, so the above code would work? If you'd like to put your comment in the form of an answer i'd be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All mainstream modern browsers (e.g. IE, FF, Webkit) accept "ad hoc" attributes<sup>1</sup> - I suspect this is for both historical and compatibility reasons.

Since `getAttribute` (should) only return the textual DOM value, this should work consistently in modern browsers and the value will not be removed or otherwise altered. (IE has messed up `getAttribute` for special attributes in  the past.)

---

<sup>1</sup> *Warning:* I cannot find supporting evidence in the [W3C DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) (or in the [W3C HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/) recommendations), as to whether a DOM implementation (or User Agent) *must accept* or *may reject* attributes not specified in the IDL.